# How to force Laravel return correct JSON data type?

Tags: laravel, types, laravel-8

In my Laravel project the model's integer type returning as string in final JSON response, like this:

```json
{
    "id": 2,
    "lang_id": "4",
    "name": "lipsum",
    "css_id": "amet",
    "css_class": "orem ipsum",
    "open_on_smalldevice": "1"
}
```

In the database the `lang_id` is `bigint`, and the `open_on_smalldevice` is `tinyint(1)` type.

The controller function looks like this:

```php
public function list(Request $request)
{
    return MyModel::whereIsPublic(true)->get();
}
```

I assert this response:

```json
{
    "id": 2,
    "lang_id": 4,
    "name": "lipsum",
    "css_id": "amet",
    "css_class": "lorem ipsum",
    "open_on_smalldevice": true
}
```

Not a big problem if boolean returning as integer (0 or 1), JavaScript handling correctly, but the `lang_id` field should be integer, not string.

How can I force Laravel to use correct data types in the response or what I miss?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/return-response-jsonarray-returns-integers-and-floats-as-strings it might be helpful.

Comment: @DanielKaminski thans, `$casts` solved the problem.